# How can I gather data in a column depending on another value from another column

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot

Because a table is worth a thousand words, here what I would like to do:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AMY | 1.5 | x1 | y1 |
| STR | 2 | x2 | y2 |
| AMY | 4.5 | x2 | y3 |
| STR | 3 | x3 | y4 |

I would like to reunite all data from Column B in a Column depending on their value of Column A.
And each Value of column A form a column Name. This, in a new dataframe.

| AMY | STR |
| --- | --- |
| 1.5 | 2 |
| 4.5 | 3 |

Thanks a lot !

I tried to make it using gather() and unite(), but it didnt give me the result i was expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the dataset have equal number of observations for ColumnA values, then select the columns and `unstack` in `base R`

```
unstack(df1[1:2], `Column B`~ `Column A`)
  AMY STR
1 1.5   2
2 4.5   3
```

Or as @onyambu mentioned, it can also work without the `form`ula specified

```
unstack(df1[1:2])
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(`Column A` = c("AMY", "STR", "AMY", "STR"), 
`Column B` = c(1.5, 
2, 4.5, 3), `Column C` = c("x1", "x2", "x2", "x3"), `Column D` = c("y1", 
"y2", "y3", "y4")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -4L
))
```

Comment: amazing solution, consider `unstack(df1[2:1])`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This solution create a list. I tried many solution to transform it as a dataframe, but the best I obtained look like this :

 
region..A1C
c(9.25295, 8.16241, 8.71599, 8.72838, 9.1661, 8.64 [...]

region..AMY
c(9.70184, 9.5071, 9.23989, 9.07524, 9.59095, 9.66 [...]

Thanks again !

Comment: df1 <- unstack(comparison[2:3], `expression`~ `Brain_region`)

Transform your list to a dataframe
df2 <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, df1))

Remove all duplicated data created to have same observation for each column
for(i in 1:ncol(df2)){
  df3[,i][duplicated(df2[,i])] <- NA 
}

For observation that are not duplicated.

Comment: @genji01 If the datasets have unequal number of observations, then it is better to use `dcast/reshape/pivot_wider` etc

Answer (score 6):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr` you could do

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
  select(ColumnA, ColumnB) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from="ColumnA", values_from="ColumnB", values_fn = list) %>% 
  unnest(cols=everything())
```